# Мне нужно поменять цвет ссылок только в списке-родителе на whitesmoke, как это сделать?

Tags: javascript

```js
let idbaseonly = document.getElementById('base-list')
for (let item of idbaseonly) {
    item.style.color = 'whitesmoke'
    item.style.textDecorationStyle = 'none'
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul id="base-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">dolor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">dolor</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если нужно, меняйте. В чем именно проблема? Ваш кусок кода вообще ни о чем не говорит. И структуру html добавьте, над которой пытаетесь выполнить действия

Comment: Мне если что менять саму структуру html менять нельзя, мне надо здесь только ссылки в родителе поменять: <ul id="base-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Да я же сказал что я новичок, не надо меня низкими оценками обстреливать 

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, HTML-код в вопрос, не в комментарий. Опишите, когда, по какому событию вам необходимо поменять цвет ссылок (здесь должна быть ссылка на инструкцию, как правильно задавать вопросы, но нет её).

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, яснее не стало из вопроса. Но раз надо помочь, то поможем, чем сможем.

```js
let idbaseonly = document.getElementById('base-list');

for (let item of idbaseonly.children) { //children в данном случае представляет собой li первого уровня
//Запись item.children[0] справедлива только для указанной вёрстки. Если она вдруг решит изменится, то можно заменить на item.querySelector('a')
    item.children[0].style.color = 'grey'; //grey (здесь он для наглядности) меняем на ваш whitesmoke
    item.children[0].style.textDecorationStyle = 'none';
}
```

```html
<ul id="base-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">dolor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">dolor</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Lorem</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">dolor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.S. Просто пользуйтесь если не поисковиком, то хотя бы console.log(). Полезная штука при отладке.